# What's the role of the yuml file in the netplan folder?

Tags: network-manager, file-format

I just learned that yAML files are useful to set network configurations. While playing around with it I mistakenly edited the yUML present in the same /etc/netplan folder and saved it using nano. While googling and hoping I could find the yUML file in its original form to recover it this question came to mind as I remember barely anything was written in it.

Comment: `.yuml`? What is this, are you sure you didn't rename your `.yaml` file?

Comment: From what people here are telling me, that's probably what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Netplan](https://netplan.io/) is fairly well documented, and it uses `.yaml` files for configuration.

There are numerous [examples](https://netplan.io/examples/) of configuration options in the documentation.

There is no such (official) thing as `.yuml` files. Maybe this file was created or renamed by mistake.